# 'shimming' some items to align with the bootstrap grid when said items are not in a container?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to align some items along the bootstrap grid but can't contain them in their normal manner. The example markup is something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="thingIneedAligned"><a>
    <div class="100percentWidthWrapper">
        <ul class="col-md-12">
            <li>thing</li>
        </ul>
    <div>
    <a class="thingIneedAligned"><a>
</div>
```

(The reason for this markup is complicated, but it's essentially an animated multi-layered menu where the background is full browser width but content adheres to the bootstrap grid. The anchor tags appear as one full-width div while the ULs slide down underneath)

The challenge here is that the above anchor tags are set to `display: block` and `float: left`. I can't 'confine' them into a typical bootstrap container as I need the other sibling elements (100percentWidthWrapper) to stretch the full width of the browser.

The only solution I've been able to come up with is JS-based. Calculate the actual position of the UL to the viewport, then add the appropriate amount of left-margin to the first anchor tag to match.

Is there a built in way to handle with this Bootstrap CSS or custom CSS? Or is JS the way to go?

UPDATE:

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/muzudaruha/1/

I need the top green box to align with the bottom green box, but both have a parent red box set to 100%. The sibling relationship is the challenge here.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: @Grundy yes...it'll take a while, but will get that up ASAP!

Comment: @Grundy JSBin link added.

Comment: @DA. -- gotchya, I'm removing my answer so that the question doesn't look 'answered'. I'll take a deeper look at the JSBin in a bit.

Comment: you can try use `.container-fluid` instead `.container`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

add the set width and auto centering margins to your menu element

```
.menu {
  border: 2px solid green;
  overflow: auto;

  width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

add left: 0 to your secondarylevel-wrapper:

```
.secondarylevel-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;

  left: 0;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/mideruzehi/3/

Comment: Close, but this is also a problem I've run into. The `left: 0` is in relation to the parent--rather than the viewport, so the secondary level menu is no longer full width of the viewport.

Comment: i'm seeing `secondarylevel-wrapper` stretch to full width of viewport: http://i.imgur.com/yWPxMAq.png

Comment: Hmm...that does look right! Can you fork the JSBin and update? For some reason, I can't get it to match what you've written.

Comment: @DA. yep, added the jsbin link (maybe you were forgetting the ; needed after `width:100%` in the `secondarylevel-wrapper` definition?